# Div height based on content

Tags: jquery, html, resize, height

I am having a page load within a content div when the document is ready. However, I also have some links that load different pages into that same content div whenever the user clicks on them. I am trying to establish the height of the content div to control something else, however once the height of the div is set on page load, I cannot seem to get the new size of the content div with the new page in it…

For example, the loaded page is 6000px, page 1 is 500px in height and page 2 is 300px in height. When the page loads, the content div is set to 6000px. Yet when I click page 1 to load it into the content div, the content div remains set to 6000px even though the content itself is only 500px in height, same for page 2, etc…

Here is the html:

```
<div id="select">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a class="load" href="javascript:void(0)" id="page1">page1</a></li>
        <li><a class="load" href="javascript:void(0)" id="page2">page2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#select { 
    width: 215px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    }

#spacer {
    border-right:2px solid #000000;
    left:10px;
    width:215px;
    position: absolute;
    }

#content {
    left: 227px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 703px;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load content on page load
    $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
                 .load("/content/" + "projects.php", null, function() {
                            contentHeight = $("#content").height();
                            selectHeight = $("#select").height();
                            $("#spacer").height(contentHeight + "px")
                                        .css({"top": selectHeight + 40 + "px" });
                 });
    //Load content on click
    $(".load").click(function(){
                    loadName = $(this).attr("id");
                    $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
                                 .load("/content/" + loadName + ".php", null, function(){
                                    contentHeight = $("#content").height();
                                    selectHeight = $("#select").height();

                                    if(selectHeight < contentHeight) {
                                    $("#spacer").css({"top": selectHeight + 40 + "px", "display": "block" })
                                                .height(contentHeight + "px");
                                    }else{        
                                    $("#spacer").css({"display": "none"}); 
                                    return;
                                    }
                    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Things would be a little more clear if we could see the HTML associated with `.load`, `#spacer`, `#content` and `#select`.

Comment: Adam, threw in the code for you

Answer (score 0):

try to change event to click , not "load"

Comment: That would disable the event to load a page into the content div which is the key component…

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the height to "auto"?

---

Edit: I looked at what you were doing and it was a bit confusing at first (a little CSS would have helped a lot).
I was wondering if maybe not assigning the variable using "var" was causing problems, but for some reason this script always worked for me.

So, I cleaned up the code a little - I wasn't sure why you were adding the selectHeight everytime since that value shouldn't change - you can just deal with that in the CSS because absolute positioning isn't required.

So, try this (no change to the HTML, so I didn't add it):

CSS

```
#spacer {
 background: #555;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding: 20px;
}
#content {
 background: #444;
 float: left;
 width: 1000px;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Load content on page load
 $("#content").html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
  .load("/content/" + "projects.php", null, function() {
   $("#spacer").height( $("#content").height() + "px");
  });

 //Load content on click
 $(".load").click(function(){
  var loadName = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#content")
   .html('<ul><li>Loading Content...</li></ul>')
   .load("/content/" + loadName + ".php", null, function(){
    $("#spacer").height( $("#content").height() + "px");   
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Well, I need an exact number as there is an algorithim in the code to define the spacer height. It is not shown now but it is unnecessary to post it. I just need to get a number value for the height.

Comment: Thanks Fudgey. There are a couple things here missing however. Ill explain a little more. The select div is on the left side, and the spacer is directly underneath the select div. Then the content is on the right side, the top is aligned to the top of the select div. The content is sometimes taller than the Select div, so the spacer then comes into play by adding a border-right attribute within the spacer div, to make a grid next to the content. So sometimes it needs to hide, hence the if/else, also sometimes some browsers render text differently so the height of select may vary…

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1.)**You can make all pages height you want to load inside the content div as the same size of the content div**

2.)**Else by Jquery**

first clear the right side content div
**$('#content').remove();**

second load your content ans set the height of the loaded document with the help of $('#content').height(...)

Refer:
http://api.jquery.com/height/